# How to create a JMS queue with topic in Docker Compose?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I’m working on containerising a Java Spring Boot application that consumes from a JMS queue.

In order to run locally with Docker I’m trying to create a local instance of ActiveMQ from the Docker compose file.

I can start an instance, but I haven’t been unable to add a queue from the Docker compose environment variables or CLI. Trying to stay light on configuration here as is the Java app I’m trying to test. Idea is for the application to consume from the queue and push a payload to the queue from SOAP UI or postman.

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a simpler way to hit the JmsListeners in the Java application?

Comment: What container image are you using? Can you share your current docker compose file?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ supports automatic destination creation, and that usually yields the best balance of developer flexibility and light-weight management. Simply have your producer and consumer connect up, and messages will start moving.

This can be customized using Authorization entries:

ref: [ActiveMQ Security](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/security)